# How to split/parse JSON data and save it into SQL server?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, split

I have a MVC controller to received JSON data which send from a WinForms application. How can I split JSON string and store it into SQL server?

Here is my controller to receive and deserialize json object:

```
Stream req = Request.InputStream;
req.Seek(0,System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
hl7View hl = null;
hl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<hl7View>(json);
//hl do have a string data like this
//"{\"data\":[{\"LOC\":\"TEST\",\"COMPANY\":\"BST\",\"MSG_ID\":\"20160701123200-112\",\"NS\":\"\",\"ROOM\":\"\",\"BED\":\"\",\"SID\":\"25444444\",\"OBS_SEQ\":\"1\",\"OBS_TIME\":\"20160701164801\",\"SEQ\":\"1\",\"ITEM\":\"8867-4\",\"ITEMLAB\":\"Heart Rate\",\"RESULT\":\"80\",\"UNIT\":\"Beats/min\",\"FLAG\":null,\"CLI_INFO\":null,\"OPID\":\"150710\"}],\"sMSG\":null}"
//what should i do here?
```

How can I split the string and store it into SQL server?

Here is the class hl7View's code:

```
public class hl7View
{
  public string sMSG {get;set;}
  public List<dataDB> Datalist {get;set;}
}
```

[database I've created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwBVx.png)

I have tried to insert data manually and it works fine. Is there any possibility to split it and then store it into a database by the time after deserializing?

Comment: What do you plan to split? Unless it's particularly large, why wouldn't you just deserialise the whole object?

Comment: Did you try to use Json.NEt? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: @John I want to split the data which deserialize from JSON object, as you can see I did deserialize json object and I get a long string data. What I want is to split that data and store it into database what I have created.

Comment: @DanielW. yes I use it to deserialize my object, what I want is to split the string and store it into my database.

Comment: _"I did deserialize json object and I get a long string data"_ - are you referring to `sMSG`? Otherwise I can't see how `hl` has a string since `hl` is an instance of `hl7View` - a class in its own right. Please can you provide a [mcve] which includes the value of `json`?

Comment: I'd give the whole string to sqlserver and have it do the "splitting" (parsing); it's less work

Comment: What is dataDB?  Is it a POCO representing a row in your table? Could you add code for dataDB?

Comment: @PhilS I created from sql server, it is just a simply table to store data inside.

Comment: Why not store your object that you deserialize in the database? Instead split the string and store the parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should need to directly add dataDB list object to sql db based on entity framework you have created.
Set foreach loop with list object of dataDB which you have already.
dbcontext.tablename.add(item) // item is foreach loop object of dataDB.
Something like below code.
`foreach (var mapping in mappings)
                {
                    mapping.UserId = UserCommitteeMappingIDWiseUserID[mapping.UserCommitteeMappingID];
                    mapping.ModifiedBy = ModifiedBy;
                    mapping.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    context.UserCommitteeMappings.AddObject(mapping);
                }`

Comment: Yea! I found that directly store the object inside sql server and split the string inside sql server is more easier!